# .NET Reflector - How do I Import a file that I exported as Assembly Source Code previously

Tags: c#, .net, xna, .net-assembly, .net-reflector

I actually exported an .exe with the "export assembly source code" option to work better with it, but when I did all the changes I wanted to do, I realized that I didn't knew how to import everything up again in an exe.
Can someone help me with my problem?

Comment: I doubt I really understand the problem, are you looking to compile your changes to same executable?

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but that would be enough.

Comment: You have to generate an assembly(exe/dll) out of your modified code, there are no tools/options (as I'm aware) that supports exporting to an assembly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inject C# code into compiled assemblies, you can use [Reflexil](http://reflexil.net/).

Note, that it runs as a plugin on top of Reflector, ILSpy, or JustDecompile.